# NHibernate: Criteria - getting list of child id's

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

I have a couple of entities in a many to many relationship.
Given the parent ID, how do I, using ICriteria, retrieve a list of children?

Code so far:

```
var driverList = DriverGroup.CreateCriteria()
    .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(groupId))
    .SetFetchMode("Drivers", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .UniqueResult<DriverGroup>().Drivers.Select(x => x.Id).
    ToArray();

var criteria = Driver.CreateCriteria()
    .Add(Restrictions.In("Id", driverList));
```

However, the SQL generated is:

```
SELECT
    this_.groupId as groupId5_1_,
    this_.name as name5_1_,
    this_.type as type5_1_,
    drivers2_.groupId as groupId3_,
    ... fields snipped ...
    drivers3_.userId as ID3,
    ... fields snipped ...
FROM
    dbo.Groups this_ 
left outer join
    dbo.Object_Rel drivers2_ 
        on this_.groupId=drivers2_.groupId
left outer join
    dbo.vwDriverSimple driverbase3_ 
        on drivers2_.ID=driverbase3_.userID 
WHERE
    this_.type=0 AND this_.groupId = @p0;
@p0 = 443 [Type: Int32 (0)]


SELECT
    this_.userID as userID10_1_,
    ... fields snipped ...
FROM
    dbo.drivers this_ 
WHERE
    this_.userID in (
        @p0, ... lots of parameters ...);
```

How do I get it to generate the following?

```
SELECT
    this_.userID as userID10_1_,
    ... fields snipped ...
FROM
    dbo.drivers this_ 
WHERE
    this_.userID in (
        SELECT
            drivers3_.userId as ID3
        FROM
            dbo.Groups this_ 
        left outer join
            dbo.Object_Rel drivers2_ 
                on this_.groupId=drivers2_.groupId
        left outer join
            dbo.vwDriverSimple driverbase3_ 
                on drivers2_.ID=driverbase3_.userID 
        WHERE
            this_.type=0 AND this_.groupId = @p0;
        @p0 = 443 [Type: Int32 (0)]
);
```

Comment: provide relevant mappings/classes

Answer (score 0):

easy, query on the child directly.

```
IList<Driver> driverList = Drivers.CreateCriteria()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Group.Id", groupId)) <-- modify according to your domain mapping
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Id"))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List<Driver>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my mapping only goes one way - from the driver group to the drivers (through the many to many table).

Comment: @Thomas- I think the best thing is to change your mapping. Do you have any reason NOT to do that?